# RepositoryItemBreadCrumbEdit1 error in devex programming

Tags: devexpress, windows-forms-designer, devexpress-mvc, devexpress-gridcontrol

" the object 'reporsitoryItemBreadCrumbEdit1' returned null for the property 'History' but this is not allowed. "

I used devex in form. I ran the program and it gave me this error. How can I fix?

Comment: you tagged WindowsForms and MVC in your post. Which are you actually using?

Comment: Post a little more information. What is the line of code that triggers this exception?